# how to make powershell shorten the long directory before ">"

Tags: powershell, directory, alias

for example, if I set an alias in profile.ps1

```
$ws='C:\Users\Jack\folder0\folder1\folder2'
```

After I cd to the workspace location`cd $ws`

It shows as below

```
PS C:\Users\Jack\folder0\folder1\folder2\>
```

Now, I'm wondering if there is a way to let it show as below or similar

```
PS $ws>
```

It's my first time ask questions on StackOverflow. if there is anything unsuitable, please give me some advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the prompt-function to do whatever you want. If you only want to check a single variable, you can do this:

```
$ws = "c:\users\frode"

function prompt {
    $CurrentLocation = $executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation.Path
    if($CurrentLocation -like "$ws*") {
        $CurrentLocation = $CurrentLocation -replace [regex]::Escape($ws), '$ws'
    }

    "PS $($CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) ";
}
```

Output:

```
PS C:\Users> cd .\frode

PS $ws> cd .\Desktop

PS $ws\Desktop>
```

If you need to support multiple variables, you can store the paths in a hashtable and check that or use `Get-Variable` to search through variables that contains a valid path. Remember to exclude ex `$PWD` which is always your current location.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i want.